# How to use template form when edit object

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a form with an embedded form (collectionType). I made a template. It works when I add a new object. But how to use this template when I edit an object ? Below my code an 2 pictures to illustrate my problem

```
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
    {% form_theme form _self %}
    {% block _paris_rencontres_row %}
        <div class="sports" id="renc-xx" style="background-color: rgba(182, 184, 185, 0.200);">
            <div
                class="row">
                {# <ul class="sports" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"></ul> #}
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    {{ form_row(form.vars.prototype.playedAt) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    {{ form_row(form.vars.prototype.sport) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    {{ form_row(form.vars.prototype.player_1) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    {{ form_row(form.vars.prototype.player_2) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    {{ form_row(form.vars.prototype.cote) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    {{ form_row(form.vars.prototype.resultat) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block body %}
        {# {{ include('paris/_form.html.twig', {form:form, button: 'Ajouter'}) }} #}
        <button type='button' id='btn-add' class='add_sport_link btn btn-primary'>Ajouter paris</button>
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="paris">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{ form_row(form.mise) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{ form_row(form.type) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{ form_row(form.win) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 matchs">
                {% if form.rencontres|length > 0 %}
                    {% for index in 0..form.rencontres|length - 1 %}
                        {{ dump(index) }}
    
                        {{ form_row(form.rencontres[index]) }}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    {{ form_row(form.rencontres) }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    {% endblock %}
```

add (form.rencontres|length == 0):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iDD0.png)

edit (form.rencontres|length > 0):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPkMz.png)

Regards
PS: Sorry for my english

EDIT: My controller

```php
@NicoHaase I dont think the problem is in the code.
I want just display my form template when I edit an object as when I add an object
`code
    /**
     * @Route("/paris/add", name="paris_add")
     */
    public function add(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $paris = new paris();
        $form = $this->createForm(ParisType::class, $paris);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($paris);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('paris');
        }
        return $this->render("paris/add.html.twig", [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/paris/{id}", name="paris_edit", requirements={"id":"\d+"})
     * @param Paris $paris
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Paris $paris)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(ParisType::class, $paris);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        return $this->render("paris/add.html.twig", [
            "paris"    => $paris,
            "form"      => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

`
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is there anything not working when you use this template in an edit controller?

Comment: hello @NicoHaase , No, it's work but the template of my form is not use when I want edit an object. (See my pictures)

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't think the problem is in the code.
I want just display my form template when I edit an object as when I add an object. I added my function add and edit in  my initial post